# Name of cognitive bias/effect causing you not to see your own spelling mistakes (because you know what you wrote)

Tags: terminology, psycholinguistics

I’m sure there’s a *name for this thing* where I can’t see my own spelling mistakes because when I’m reading what I’ve written, I know what it’s supposed to say. So, I’m blind to having typed “exmaple” instead of “example” because I know I meant to write the latter. Anyone but me would spot the typo in an instance. Does anyone know the name of this cognitive bias? Is it even a cognitive bias?

Comment: This bias (if you can really call it a bias) may be _stronger_ when it’s your own writing, but it’s definitely there even when it’s other people’s writings too. That’s why text should always be proofread at least three or four times – you will inevitably miss mistakes each time around.

Comment: It is first of all an observer bias and maybe a survivor bias in first approximation, unless it's a systemic bias in the case that the divergent spelling is consistent. I mean, other than mere unconcious syncopations the principle is much the same with any text that's longer than a word in a sense which we might judge, eg. internet comments being incorrect.